# Adding docs to Firebase in Prod Mode using @angular/fire

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

Im currently having troubles adding documents to a collection. I allowed read, write, create, update, delete privileges on authenticated users but it i get following error message:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): FirebaseError: [code=permission-denied]: The caller does not have permission
> FirebaseError: The caller does not have permission

Rules on Firebase(Firestore):

```
 service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write, create, update, delete: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Code trying to add a doc to firestore:

```
    createUserEntry(user) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.firestore.collection('users').add(
        this.toFirebaseUser(user))
          .then((success) => {
            resolve(success);
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            this.alert.alertToast(error.message);
            reject(error);
          });
        });
  }

  toFirebaseUser(user) {
    console.log(user);
    return {
      displayName: user.displayName,
      email: user.email,
      uid: user.uid
    };
  }
```

Would be great if anyone knows what's causing the issue.

Comment: I was wondering if this is a problem of the rules configuration or another thing. If you just put `allow read, write;` without the auth condition, you get the same error?

Comment: And try to add `rules_version = '2';` in the first line, before `service cloud.firestore`